# How to use array with foreach in PHP

Tags: php

I'm try to using array in PHP by finding it index and keys as foreach.
example I want to get **$k["ab"]** or **$ro["hh"]** but I can't get it

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "test"=>array(
        "some"=>"d",
        "hello"=>"e",
        "ther"=>"a"
    ),
    "ab"=>array(
        "ad"=>"tt",
        "de"=>"jj",
        "hh"=>"uu")
    );
    foreach($data as $k=>$ro){
          var_dump($k);
    } 
?>
```

Comment: its inside another dimension, add another `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try Below :

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "test"=>array(
        "some"=>"d",
        "hello"=>"e",
        "ther"=>"a"
    ),
    "ab"=>array(
        "ad"=>"tt",
        "de"=>"jj",
        "hh"=>"uu")
    );
    foreach($data as $k=>$ro){
        if($k == "ab"){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_R($ro);
            echo 'HH Value ===> '.$ro['hh'];
        }
    } 
?>
```

And Want to get All values and Keys Try Below For Each :

```
foreach($data as $k=>$ro){
        foreach($ro as $inner_key => $inner_value){
            echo "<br/> Key ===> ".$inner_key."==== value =====>".$inner_value;
        }

    }
```

Comment: No. The echo tags are incomplete, and the PHP functions should not be in mixed case. Also, advised to make good use of `PHP_EOL`.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better learn the structure of multi-dimensional array.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "test"=>array(
        "some"=>"d",
        "hello"=>"e",
        "ther"=>"a"
    ),
    "ab"=>array(
        "ad"=>"tt",
        "de"=>"jj",
        "hh"=>"uu")
);
foreach($data as $key => $values){
    echo $key; // which will output "test", "ab", which are the array keys
    print_r($values); // which will output the contents of the inner array (e.g. array("some"=>"d","hello"=>"e","ther"=>"a") )

    // to obtain the inner array values, you can either use another foreach...
    foreach($values as $k => $v) {
       echo $k . ', ' . $v; // which will output "ad, tt", etc
    }
    // ...or specify which key to obtain
    if(isset($values["ad"])) { echo $values["ad"]; } 
    // isset() must be used, as the key does not exist in 1st inner array
}
?>
```